# How to form multiple noun clauses with “dass”, e.g. “dass ..., und, dass ...”?

Tags: english-to-german, conjunction, subordinate-clause

The sentence below uses two noun clauses with *that (dass)* through the use of coordinating conjunction *and.*
Which coordinating conjunction or formation would be the most suitable conjunction in this case in German?

> She thinks that it's OK to not attend school and that it's acceptable to disregard homework

My best guess would be to also use *und:*

> Sie meint, dass es in Ordung ist, die Schule nicht zu besuchen und, dass es akzeptabel ist, Hausaufgaben zu missachten.

Comment: **und** is fine here. For interpunctation and more natural wording, see Christian Geiselmanns answer. I don't know how to answer your question in more than one sentence :)

Answer (score 8):

Your only mistake is the comma. Other than that, it's correct.

> Sie meint, dass es in Ordnung ist, die Schule nicht zu besuchen, und dass es akzeptabel ist, Hausaufgaben zu missachten.

Explanation:
If you connect two clauses of the same level with *und* or any other coordinating conjunction, no comma is required.
The reason for the comma before *und* is that it is the comma that ends the "erweiteter Infinitiv"-clause. Without that clause, there's just one comma after the verb of your main clause.

> Sie meint, dass es in Ordnung ist und dass es akzeptabel ist.

Answer (score 6):

Die richtige Zeichensetzung im Deutschen ist:

> Sie meint, dass es in Ordnung ist, die Schule nicht zu besuchen, und dass es akzeptabel ist, Hausaufgaben nicht zu machen.

Die Zeichensetzung folgt hier zwei einfachen Regeln:

- "Dass-Sätze" werden mit Komma abgetrennt (nach dem Hauptsatz, **vor** dem ersten 'dass'!)
- Teilsätze mit zu+Infinitiv werden per Komma abgetrennt - und zwar vorne **und** hinten, sofern es am Ende noch weiter geht (und nicht sowieso ein Punkt dem ganzen Satz ein Ende setzt).

Wenn man das anwendet, kann man eigentlich hier nicht viel falsch machen.

Comment: Gute Antwort. Aber ich glaube, sie sollte auf Englisch sein, da die Frage auch auf Englisch gestellt wurde.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the second comma, which is in the wrong place as already pointed out, your sentence is OK.

From a stylistic POV, the two "dass" parts sound a bit clumsy. You can do with an infinitive alone.

From a very strict grammatical POV, the sentence asks for the *Konjunktiv* (because both is actually not OK)

> Sie meint es sei in Ordnung, die Schule nicht zu besuchen und [es wäre] akzeptabel, die Hausaufgaben zu missachten.

The second "es wäre" can be left out and is optional.